# Determine grid size from data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code I am pulling a data-attribute called grid size from the HTML. When grid size is pulled through I want to write a statement that says if the value is "large" then the x and y co-orginates are... and if the value is "small" then the x and y co-ordinates are... I have given it a go but I can't get it working. Can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Here is the statement that pulls it from the HTML

```
    $('li[data-number-input],li[data-completion-number]').each(function(){
    numberInput.push($(this).attr('data-number-input'));
    completionNumber.push($(this).attr('data-completion-number'));
    gridSize.push($(this).attr('data-grid-size'));
});
```

Here is the statement I have written

```
if ($(this).data('grid-size') == "large") {
    gridColumns = 4;
    gridRows = 4;
}
else {
   gridColumns = 6;
   gridRows = 8;
}
```

Here is the html

```
<li data-number-input="6" data-completion-number="1" data-grid-rows="8" data-grid-columns="6" data-grid-size="large"></li>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `if (gridSize.push($(this).attr('data-grid-size') == "large") {`? It doesn't make any sense and also has a syntax error.

Comment: If the value in the html is large @undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code, you have missed a `)` for the `push` method and I'm not sure why you are using push method in an if statement, you can use `data` method:

```
if ($(this).data('grid-size') === "large") {
   // ...
} else {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok so now it is just going straight to the else statement everytime. Its not recognising "large" @undefined

Comment: True yours does work. Could it be the gridColumns = 8;
   gridRows = 6; part @undefined

Comment: @IronSpoon No, that doesn't affect the if statement, are you sure you are using this code?

Comment: @IronSpoon in your fiddle there is no `<li data-number-input="6" data-completion-number="1" data-grid-rows="8" data-grid-columns="6" data-grid-size="large"></li>` element, hint: `data` only returns the data of the first matched element, you should use `each` or other methods based on your requirement.

Comment: There is at the bottom of the <ul>. I took data-grid-rows="8" data-grid-columns="6" out though because it wasn't being used @undefined

Comment: @IronSpoon Okay, I changed the selector to `if ($('#wordlist li:last').data('grid-size') == "large") {` http://jsfiddle.net/3ABnZ/